# How can I delete data off the DOM and the backend?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is some JavaScript code from the frontend:

```js
const deleteItem = () => {
  fetch(ITEMS_URL + `/${event.target.dataset.ItemId}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
  }).then(removeItem(event.target.dataset.itemId));
  clearForm(); 
};

const removeItem = (id) => {
  let cardToRemove = document.getElementById(`item-${id}`);
  cardToRemove.parentElement.removeChild(cardToRemove);
};
```

and here is the backend code in Ruby from the controller:

```html
# DELETE /items/1
    def destroy
      @item.destroy
    end
```

When I open my webpage, I can click "delete item" and it is gone off the DOM. As soon as I refresh the page, the item I just deleted is back. How do I delete it so that it doesn't show up even when I refresh the page?

Comment: is yr javascript out side of rails ?

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting your items only on DOM. But they are still persisted in your database. To delete them from database you have to send request to your `ItemsController` via `fetch()`. Something like this:

```js
const removeItem = (id) => {
  return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/items/${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  }).then(() => {
    let cardToRemove = document.getElementById(`item-${id}`);
    cardToRemove.parentElement.removeChild(cardToRemove);)
  }
}
```